# CodeIgniter Form Verification

Tags: php, codeigniter, verification

I'm trying to use form verification in code igniter;

My Controller Rule looks like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('salesOrder', 'Sales Order Number', 'required');
```

My View looks like this:

```
form_input(array('name' => 'salesOrder', 'value'=>$value)) . form_error('salesOrder');
```

This doesnt work - the rule is triggered no matter the value entered. However, if I change the name values to the following so that:

My Controller Rule looks like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('1', 'Sales Order Number', 'required');
```

My View looks like this:

```
form_input(array('name' => '1', 'value'=>$value) . form_error('1');
```

It works fine, verifies and continues to run the script as expected. Any clue as to why this might happen?

Thanks

Comment: pls always be responsive to the answers given , mark it with green check and do upvote if you find it helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

I just check your code you are doing a mistake here:-

```
 form_input(array('name' => 'salesOrder', 'value'=>$value)) . form_error('salesOrder');
```

should be:-

```
 echo form_input(array('name' => 'salesOrder', 'value'=>$value)) ;

 echo form_error('salesOrder');
```

**or just put echo before your code where you are concatenating input and error.**

You can use below script which will show all errors:-

```
echo validation_errors();
```

You can find a better explanation at below link with example:-

https://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-codeigniter/